# CSS Flexbox, Right to Left Content, Aligned Right, Justified Bottom

Tags: css

Trying to layout the following tiles in CSS, but can't seem to find the right combination of align/justify.

[image]

Here's what I got so far:

```css
    .container {
        border: 3px solid red;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: flex-end;
        justify-content: flex-end;        
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
    }
    .item {
        border: 3px solid red;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
        <div class="item">7</div>
    </div>
```

The result is not right to left and it's not "pushed" to the right side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```css
.container {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.item {
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

Instead of using:

```css
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
```

You could also use:

```css
flex-flow: column wrap-reverse;
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
        border: 3px solid red;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
        align-items: flex-end;
        justify-content: flex-end;        
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
    }
    .item {
        border: 3px solid red;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
        <div class="item">7</div>
    </div>
```

Super close, just need to change your wrap direction

Answer (score 1):

you can add one thing to your parent :

```
direction:rtl;
```

and it will be ok ;)